# Bug in Code is Killing me

Tags: php

The problem is that, even after I have cleared my cookies, it is still displaying the page, which my first if statement is supposed to take care of.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/premind/includes/vars.php');

if (!isset($_COOKIE['emailaddress'])) {
    header("location:/premind/notloggedin.php");
}

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");

mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());

$sql4 = 'SELECT `aname`, `date`, `useremail`, `aid` FROM `data`';

$result4 = mysql_query($sql4) or die("<br />" . mysql_error());

$countrows2 = mysql_num_rows($result4);

if (!$result4) {
    echo "Cannot show assignments!";
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) {
    if ($row['useremail'] == $_COOKIE['emailaddress']) {
        echo $row['aid'] . ". " . $row['aname'] . " -- " . $row['date'] . "<br />";
        echo "<br />";
    }
    elseif ($countrows2 == 0) {
        echo "<h1>No assignments found!</h1>";
    }
}

if ($countrows2 == 0) {
    echo "<h1>No assignments found!</h1>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried checking strlen($_COOKIE['emailaddress']) < 1 ?

Comment: Please don't use cookies to authorize users, they can simply add and edit them!

Comment: Yes, I tried strlen(), same result.  

@ComFreek Well, I had the same issue with sessions.

Comment: 1.Make sure having `error reporting` on `E_ALL` , maybe your `header` function doesn't work from some reason. 2.Try to `echo` the cookie's value before the `IF` please and share the output with us.

Comment: Can you use a more meaningful title? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41976/question-title-that-doesnt-describe-the-problem

Comment: Well, I am not going to ask my question in the title, I'm going to ask it in the body. So to be completely honest, no.

Comment: If you can think of a title that describes the problem in a reasonable amount of words, you're welcome to edit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['emailaddress'])) {
   header("Location: /premind/notloggedin.php");
   exit();
}
```

Might also want to check !empty() just in case.

Also:

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password");
```

No need for the quotes here.

```
mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
```

Is just fine

On a side note, as ComFreek mentioned, cookies are not a secure way to authorize users.

Comment: Tried empty(), with the exit() function.  The empty call didn't do anything, and exit() made the page turn blank.

Comment: well isset is fine then. Note the change I made to header(), apply it and try again

Comment: Yes, I made the change.  Thank you.  Same result, however.

This is really weird.  Because I know the cookie is gone, yet it still thinks it's there.

Comment: If the page turns blank with exit(), then it acknowledges that the cookie is not there.

Comment: I tried to use sessions, but I had the same problem, so I tried using cookies.  This is going to be used at a school, so I don't think anybody is interested in screwing with it.  But thank you for the tip!

Comment: I figured, but the issue is that when the cookie is not there, it is supposed to redirect to notloggedin.php.

Comment: @DustinStalin There are always some students who have the knowledge to do this but anyway you should always use the best security wherever your application will be run!

Comment: True true. I'll consider changing it. But I need to solve this for the time being.

Comment: @DustinStalin All I can tell you is this: This code is perfectly functional/valid/correct. There's either something else preventing it from working (perhaps something was already sent and error reporting is off?) or your browser cache is still intact. In which case the best way would be to either try it on a different browser or a different PC altogether

Comment: Well I very much appreciate the review and your effort to fix it is much appreciated as well. So thank you. I'll give it a shot on another computer because I have cleared the cache and cookies and EVERYTHING I can clear. And still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think there

- should be space between location & url
- try using full domain instead,

so try the following code

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['emailaddress'])) {
    header("location: http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/premind/notloggedin.php");
    exit();
}
```

Let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `die()` after the header statement. The `Location` header means nothing if a page comes afterwards.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['emailaddress'])) {
    header("location:/premind/notloggedin.php");
    die();
}
```

Comment: Is `die()` preferred over `exit()` in this scenario?

Comment: No, there's no difference. http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: @Colin: Afaik there is no meaningful difference between the two

Comment: die() and exit() both made the page blank.

Comment: Thanks - I suppose I could have looked it up. I didn't realize it was that straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Robus as far as implementation goes.  You should also verify that `include('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/premind/includes/vars.php');` is not printing anything out, and that you don't have any white space before your `<?php` tag.

You can use the [headers_sent](http://docs.php.net/headers_sent) function to determine if the issue is indeed header related

```
if (!headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
   header("Location: /premind/notloggedin.php");
   exit();
} else {
    echo "Headers already sent in $filename on line $linenum";
    exit;
}
```